# jQuery.Cycle plugin start at position

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have the cycle pulgin work on a page with a carousel. I need the Cycle to start at a certain position, is this posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in options object:

```
startingSlide: 0,     // zero-based index of the first slide to be displayed
```

[Source](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)